# Award results. Help?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build an sql query with no success. As I'm a newbie i hope to find your help.

Scenery: a store is organizing an award among its customers. Here is the database they have:

```
__________________________________________________________________
id  |    name     |   date     |   time   |   item   |  section  |
__________________________________________________________________

01  |  J. Smith   | 2011-10-30 | 10:12:56 |  shoes   |   sport   |
02  |  J. Smith   | 2011-10-27 | 11:14:19 |  T-shirt |   sport   |
03  |  M. Douglas | 2011-11-01 | 04:00:42 | keyboard | computer  |
04  |  R. Obrian  | 2010-12-31 | 11:33:57 |  webcam  | computer  |
05  |  M. Douglas | 2011-01-07 | 12:42:00 |  webcam  | computer  |
06  |  J. Smith   | 2011-02-05 | 02:30:51 |  T-shirt |   sport   |
07  |  J. Smith   | 2011-05-12 | 06:55:14 |  bike    |   sport   |
08  |  J. Smith   | 2011-03-15 | 09:59:22 |  shoes   |   sport   |
09  |  J. Smith   | 2011-09-09 | 08:10:36 |  webcam  | computer  |
10  |  J. Smith   | 2011-06-09 | 10:00:38 |microphone| computer  |
```

I want to make a top 10 list of customers for each section, with the following criteria: the best buyer is who bought the major number of DIFFERENT items. In case of same results (same number of different items bought) among customers, the best buyer is who 1st (date & time) bought all his items.

I'd like to have, for example, the following top 10 results table:

```
                          SPORT
 ____________________________________________________________ 
 |  name   |   items bought (different)  |     Date & Time   |
 ____________________________________________________________ 
 | XXXYYY  |             16              | 2011-10-05  @07:15| 
 | ZZZZTT  |             16              | 2011-10-05  @08:10| 
 | QQHAIJ  |             16              | 2011-10-06  @10:35| 
 | TTTSFT  |             15              | 2011-11-03  @12:22|
 | LIUREN  |             14              | 2011-11-14  @16:10|
 | ODIRNU  |             9               | 2011-07-03  @14:18|
 | OIXUED  |             8               | 2011-11-20  @03:03|
 | SUHDKO  |             7               | 2011-02-02  @22:51|
 | TNODJH  |             7               | 2011-06-10  @12:55|
 | ENOSJR  |             6               | 2011-04-04  @11:39|
 _____________________________________________________________
```

The queries must be different for each section, id est i must have a different string (and table of results) for SPORT, COMPUTER...et cetera.

Who can help me? Thanks in advance!

Bob.

Comment: It'll help if you post sample expected results based on the sample customer table data you provided.. :)

Comment: Do you want to select top 10 for each section or the section will be passed to the query?? (i. e greatest per group) if so i think you should look at the tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group , you will find similer issues

Comment: "the best buyer is who 1st (date & time) bought all his items." can you explain it, is best buyer who bought last item early or first item early?

Comment: @ Utku Yıldırım: the best buyer is who bought "LAST item early", as you wrote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Early first item purchaser wins

```
SELECT name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT item) AS items, 
    MIN(ADDTIME(`date`,`time`)) AS `datetime`
FROM purchase
WHERE section = 'computer'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY items DESC, `datetime` ASC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Example table result:

```
|- name       -|- items -|- datetime            -|
|- M. Douglas -|- 2     -|- 2011-01-07 12:42:00 -|
|- J. Smith   -|- 2     -|- 2011-06-09 10:00:38 -|
|- R. Obrian  -|- 1     -|- 2010-12-31 11:33:57 -|
```

### Early last item purchaser wins

```
SELECT name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT item) AS items, 
    MAX(ADDTIME(`date`,`time`)) AS `datetime`
FROM purchase
WHERE section = 'computer'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY items DESC, `datetime` ASC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Example table result:

```
|- name       -|- items -|- datetime            -|
|- J. Smith   -|- 2     -|- 2011-09-09 08:10:36 -|
|- M. Douglas -|- 2     -|- 2011-11-01 04:00:42 -|
|- R. Obrian  -|- 1     -|- 2010-12-31 11:33:57 -|
```

Comment: Hi! I tried your code but i have some doubts. In case of same number of purchases (different items) the previous position must be occupied by the buyer who purchased before all his items. I made some tests and I noticed that for sure date/time appearing in each row is referred to the 1st item purchased. In my criteria i need to show (and order buyers with same items purchased) in function fo the date/time of the last item bought. :)

Comment: @user1056439 I didnt really get what your meaning. `Early last item purchaser wins` gives last item purchase date. If its not what you want, can you explain with an example

Comment: @user1056439 A Reminder: If section is computer, this code gives last computer section item purchase time, do you need last any item purchase time ?

Comment: Hey Utku Yıldırım now it's all ok. I meant "Early last item purchaser wins" and your code is perfect! I didn't notice that you published both examples so i used only the 1st one, not useful for me. Thank you very much, you've ben great!

Comment: Dont forget to select 1 of answer, so question will be answered. I'm glad i helped

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
SELECT 
    t1.name, 
    COUNT(*) as `Distinct items bought`, 
    MIN(t1.computedDateTime) as `Date And Time` 
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        name,  MIN(ADDTIME(date, time)) as computedDateTime, item
    FROM 
        tablename
    WHERE
        Section = "sport"
    GROUP BY
        name, item
    ) t1
GROUP BY
    name
ORDER BY 
    count(*), MIN(computedDateTime)  DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The inner select (should) produce a table of distinct items bought by individuals, limited to the section `"sport"`.  Then the outer select identifies total number of these distinct purchases by name, and sorts them.

I'm not set up to test this right now, so use carefully.  My biggest concern is the `ADDTIME` function to combine date and time, which I have not used before.

Comment: Unfortynately there is something of wrong. After executing the query i read the following message:"Every derived table must have its own alias". As newbie i have no idea where to modify the code.

Comment: I added an alias to the inner query, and updated the SELECT clause.  See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, date, time, COUNT(DISTINCT item) AS NumOfItems
FROM Purchased
WHERE section = 'sport'
ORDER BY NumOfItems, date, time
LIMIT 10
```